# Как построить корректный запрос MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть примерно такая таблица (date-дата, count-количество обращений пользователя в эту дату)
date     | user | count
12-01-2020 | sam  | 2
12-01-2020 | ben  | 7
12-01-2020 | nil  | 3
13-01-2020 | sam  | 4
13-01-2020 | bob  | 1
14-01-2020 | bob  | 3
Необходимо построить запрос на получением самого активного пользователя для каждой даты, т.е. получить что-то типа такого:
 date      | user | count
12-01-2020 | ben  | 7
13-01-2020 | sam  | 4
14-01-2020 | bob  | 3